# mySQL update "timecreated" column but add one second to each subsequent entry

Tags: mysql

I've got a timecreated field which I need to populate with the time... But I'd like to have the time autoincrement by one second for each subsequent entry so that none of the times are the same... The time itself doesn't actually matter, I just don't want any of them to be the same.

TABLE: notes
COLUMN: timecreated

I'd basically just like to have:
Timecreated:  12:00:01
Timecreated:  12:00:02

And so on... Thanks again guys!

[EDIT]

Full table structure:
TABLE: notes
COLUMNS: NO-ID (key), objectid, partnerid, note, datecreated, timecreated, datemodified

Comment: Is this a one-time operation to populate for existing rows, or do you need this to keep incrementing into the future based on _existing_ rows?

Comment: What happens if you add a lot of rows at one time - the timecreated values could be in the future?

Comment: Oh, does your table have an auto_increment PK column already? If so, you can add the PK to a base timestamp with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

Comment: Yea it's just a one time entry. I don't need this feature to continue later, just this one use. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since `NO-ID` (weird name for a column, but that's not the point) is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can simply add its value (which is by definition unique) to a base UNIX timestamp.  You will want to start far enough in the past that you don't run out of values, though that's only an issue if you have millions and millions of rows.

So starting from `2012-01-01 00:00:00` for example:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 00:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 00:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                            1325397600 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Update all rows adding the primary key value to that base timestamp:

```
UPDATE `notes` SET `timecreated` = FROM_UNIXTIME(1325397600 + `NO-ID`);
```

If you have deleted rows, they won't be consecutive seconds, but they are still unique.

You don't even really *have* to start from a base timestamp. You could just start from 0, which is Jan 1, 1970 plus or minus your server's timezone.

```
UPDATE `notes` SET `timecreated` = FROM_UNIXTIME(`NO-ID`);
```

Results in timestamps like

```
1970-01-01 00:00:01
1970-01-01 00:00:02
1970-01-01 00:00:03
1970-01-01 00:00:04
...
```

#### Update after comments:

To increment the `datecreated` field by one day, use the same pattern, but with `DATE_ADD()`:

```
UPDATE `notes` SET `datecreated` = DATE_ADD('2012-01-01', INTERVAL `NO-ID` DAY)
```

Use caution though, it is a lot easier to run out of days from your starting date than it is to run out of seconds...

Comment: That worked perfectly! Is there a way to perform a similar function to the datecreated field as well, so that the dates increment by one day?